# Pass Long datatype array in JAX-WS as a parameter

Tags: arrays, jax-ws

I am trying to pass a Long datatype array to one of my webservivce method.
My Webservice method is looks follows:

```
public String calculate(Long[] values)
{
//my code here to process the array
}
```

From the client side i am calling the webservice like follows

```
Long[] data=new Long[1];
data[0]=1;
proxy = webService.getClient(wsdlURL)
String response=proxy.calculate(data);
```

But it throwing me the exception **javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class [Ljava.lang.Long; nor any of its super class is known to this context.**

Based on googling i understand this one because of JAXB unable to marshall the Long array. But i dont know how to fix it. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `ArrayList()` on the client side:

```
List<Long> data = new ArrayList<Long>();
data.add(new Long(1));
data.add(new Long(5));
proxy = webService.getClient(wsdlURL)
String response=proxy.calculate(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe BigInteger would work for you? That seems to be the default mapping from xml integer to java type.